# Change table to another style using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to retrieve table data from my web site using curl. Now I can login to my site and grab all my table data.

Problem is I want to change my table style(format). How to solve it?

Comment: Use a DOM parser. There are many available.

Comment: If it is your website why do you need curl?

Comment: Sorry. Can you give me examples or tutorials about this